# sequelize.js relationship validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Imagine I have two models:

```
var Movie = sequelize.define('movies', {
 /* model definition */
})

var Genre = sequelize.define('genres', {
 /* model definition */
});

Movie.hasMany(Genre);
Genre.hasMany(Movie);
```

If I wanted to stipulate that a Movie MUST have at least one Genre, how would I go about doing that?

I've looked in the obvious places.  My initial idea was to build(), validate() and save(), however looking at the source .validate() only accommodates fields defined in the model definition.

e.g.

```
Genre.find({where:{'name':'horror})
  .success(function (horrorGenre) {
    var movie = Movie.build({..});
    movie.addGenre(horrorGenre);
    if (! movie.validate()) { // This doesn't consider related data
      movie.save();
    }
 });
```

So I figure I need to implement some kind of custom validation mechanism, but I'm not entirely sure where to start.

*NOTE* I'm maintaining my own fork of Sequelize, so this is more of a question of how I might go about modifying the Sequelize source to do what I want it to do versus throwing together a hacky solid implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to search for genre objects in database and call `addGenre` for `movie`

```
Genre.findall({where:{'name':["genre1","genre1"]})
  .success(function (genres) {
    if(genres.length==0){
      console.log("Genres were not found!"); 
      // exit somehow maybe res.json(200,{"msg","not ok"});
    }
    var movie = Movie.build({..});
    var queryChainer = new Sequelize.Utils.QueryChainer;
    for(var i = 0 ; i != genres.length ; i++){
      queryChainer.add(movie.addGenre(genres[i].id));
    }
    queryChainer.run().success(function(){}).error(function(){});
});
```

this way you will know that at least 1 genre will be added to submitted movie!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer the question.  I want to validate the model BEFORE I insert anything into a DB.

Comment: Apologies, I mis-read the example.  It is a solution, but not one I'm particularly happy with.  I want to program to an interface, specifically Sequelizes interface.  I'm maintaining my own branch, this is more about how I can modify Sequelize source to do what I want it to do, rather than hacking something together.